# Create a list of years from a function

Tags: python, datetime

I am aware of how to loop through days using `dt.timedelta()`. However, there does not seem to be an applicable use of timedelta to do this for years. For example:

```
def list_dates(start, end):
    num_days = (end - start).days
    return [start + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(num_days)]


start_date = dt.date(2017, 4, 10)
end_date = dt.date(2017, 5, 1)
date_list = list_dates(start_date, end_date)
```

This outputs a list of days that range from 4-10-2017 through 5-1-2017.

Now, I want to do the same thing as the above function but for years. For example, say I provide a start and end year (2010 and 2019). The function would then spit out a list of years from 2010 to 2019.

Comment: Since you're not interested in the month or day (which make up a datetime), just using an integer-based `range()` and forget about `timedelta`.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to understand why `range(2010, 2020)` would be inadequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.date_range` and specify the number of periods you'd like:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

start = datetime(2017, 4, 10).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

end = datetime(2019, 5, 1).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")


list(pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, periods = 3).year)

#Output
[2017, 2018, 2019]
```

Comment: Is `pd` here `pandas`?

Comment: Yep, import pandas as pd

Answer (score 0):

Here's a type-checked implementation that I think suits your requirements:

```
import datetime

def list_years_from_dates(start: datetime.date, end: datetime.date) -> range:
    return range(start.year, 1 + end.year)
```